# How to find alternative value for particular id in FROM clause query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find detailed requirement and details are as below. The given query is giving results for the quote_revision_id available in Query A but if quote_revivsion_id is not present in Query but the other quote_reivsion_ids present in other than Query A then all the details should display for those quote_revision_id.

I have already mentioned in my expected result like from the given query I need the results for Quote_revision_id 5 & 6 also but with my given query those records are not coming.

**Oracle Version: 12.1.0**

Please find below the detailed requirement and necessary details,

**Tables:**

```
create table t1 (quote_revision_id number, qty number,item_parts 
varchar2(100),cost number, resale number, item_tag varchar2(10))
/
create table t2 (opportunity_id number,rebate number)
/
create table t3 (revision_id number,quote_id number)
/
create table t4 (quote_id number,opportunity_id number)
/
create table t5 (opportunity_id number,shipping_fee_taxes number,
agent_commissions number, total_program_costs number, service_fees number)
```

/

**Insert:**

```
insert into t1 values (1,10,'P1',100,100,null)
/
insert into t1 values (2,20,'P2',110,110,null)
/
insert into t1 values (3,10,'P3',120,120,null)
/
insert into t1 values (4,30,'P4',130,130,null)
/
insert into t1 values (5,20,'P5',140,null,null)
/   
insert into t1 values (6,10,'P6',150,150,'5.0')
/

insert into t2 values (100,10)
/
insert into t2 values (101,20)
/
insert into t2 values (102,10)
/
insert into t2 values (103,0)
/
insert into t2 values (104,20)
/
insert into t2 values (105,10)
/

insert into t3 values (1,10)
/
insert into t3 values (2,20)
/
insert into t3 values (3,30)
/
insert into t3 values (4,40)
/
insert into t3 values (5,50)
/
insert into t3 values (6,60)
/

insert into t4 values (10,100)
/  
insert into t4 values (20,101)
/
insert into t4 values (30,102)
/
insert into t4 values (40,103)
/
insert into t4 values (50,104)
/
insert into t4 values (60,105)
/

insert into t5 values (100,1,2,3,4)
/
insert into t5 values (101,1,2,3,4)
/
insert into t5 values (102,1,2,3,4)
/
insert into t5 values (103,1,2,3,4)
/
insert into t5 values (104,1,2,3,4)
/
insert into t5 values (105,1,2,3,4)
/

commit
/
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(NVL(a.total_resale,0)),2) total_resale,
     ROUND(SUM(NVL(a.total_cost,0)),2) total_cost,
     ROUND(SUM(nvl(e.total_adjustments,0)),2) total_adjustments,
       a.quote_revision_id,
     CASE WHEN SUM(NVL(a.total_resale,0)) <> 0  THEN
        ROUND(((SUM(NVL(a.total_resale,0)) -
               SUM(NVL(a.total_cost,0))) /
               SUM(NVL(a.total_resale,0))*100),2)
        ELSE 0
     END parts_margin,
     ROUND(SUM(nvl(a.net_margin,0)),2) net_margin,
     SUM(nvl(c.total_no_of_parts_requested,0))  total_no_of_parts_requested,
     SUM(nvl(d.total_no_of_parts_quoted,0)) total_no_of_parts_quoted,
     (SUM(nvl(c.total_no_of_parts_requested,0))- 
SUM(nvl(d.total_no_of_parts_quoted,0))) total_no_of_part_not_quoted
FROM
(SELECT  SUM(NVL(t1.resale,0) * NVL(t1.qty,0)) total_resale,
              SUM(NVL(t1.cost,0) * NVL(t1.qty,0)) total_cost,
              t1.quote_revision_id quote_revision_id,
              CASE WHEN (SUM(nvl(t1.resale,0) * nvl(t1.qty,0)) +
                         SUM(nvl(t5.service_fees,0))) <> 0 THEN
                (((SUM(NVL(t1.resale,0) * NVL(t1.qty,0)) +
                    SUM(NVL(t5.service_fees,0))) -
                    (SUM(NVL(t1.cost,0) * NVL(t1.qty,0)) +
                     (SUM(NVL(t2.rebate,0) + NVL(t5.shipping_fee_taxes,0) +
                         NVL(t5.agent_commissions,0) + 
    NVL(t5.total_program_costs,0)))- (sum(nvl(t5.service_fees,0))))) /
                  (SUM(NVL(t1.resale,0) * NVL(t1.qty,0)) +
                   SUM(nvl(t5.service_fees,0))) *100) 
              ELSE 0 END net_margin
         FROM t1 ,
              t2,
              t3,
              t4,
              t5
        WHERE t1.quote_revision_id = t3.revision_id AND
              t3.quote_id = t4.quote_id AND
              t2.opportunity_id = t4.opportunity_id AND
              t5.opportunity_id = t4.opportunity_id AND
              t1.resale is not null AND
              ((t1.item_tag <> '5.0' and t1.item_tag <> 5) or (t1.item_tag 
       is null)) --added constraint for excluding parts with item_tag 5 for           
       both alphanumeric and number values of item tag
     GROUP BY t1.quote_revision_id)a,
     (SELECT  t2.opportunity_id,
              MAX(t1.quote_revision_id) quote_revision_id
        FROM  t2,
              t4,
              t3,
              t1
       WHERE  t2.opportunity_id = t4.opportunity_id AND
              t4.quote_id = t3.quote_id AND
              t3.revision_id = t1.quote_revision_id   
    GROUP BY  t2.opportunity_id) b,
    (SELECT  t1.quote_revision_id,
              COUNT(t1.item_parts) total_no_of_parts_requested
        FROM  t1
    GROUP BY  t1.quote_revision_id) c,
    (SELECT  t1.quote_revision_id,
            COUNT(t1.item_parts)
         total_no_of_parts_quoted
        FROM  t1
        where t1.COST is not null
        and t1.RESALE is not null
    GROUP BY  t1.quote_revision_id) d,
            (SELECT  t2.opportunity_id,
             ((SUM(NVL(t2.rebate,0) +
                  NVL(t5.shipping_fee_taxes,0) +
                  NVL(t5.agent_commissions,0) +
                  NVL(t5.total_program_costs,0))) -
              SUM(nvl(t5.service_fees,0))) total_adjustments
              FROM  t2,
              t5
        where t2.opportunity_id = t5.opportunity_id
    GROUP BY  t2.opportunity_id
    ) e

  where a.quote_revision_id  = b.quote_revision_id AND      
   c.quote_revision_id(+) = b.quote_revision_id AND
   d.quote_revision_id(+) = b.quote_revision_id AND
   e.opportunity_id(+) = b.opportunity_id
 group by a.quote_revision_id
  order by a.quote_revision_id;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+--------+------+------+--------------+----+--------+----+----+-----+
| RESALE | COST | Adj. | Quote_Rev_id | PM |   NM   | PR | PQ | PNQ |
+--------+------+------+--------------+----+--------+----+----+-----+
|   1000 | 1000 |   12 |            1 |  0 |   -0.8 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|   2200 | 2200 |   22 |            2 |  0 |  -0.82 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|   1200 | 1200 |   12 |            3 |  0 |  -0.66 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|   3900 | 3900 |    2 |            4 |  0 |   0.05 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|      0 |    0 |    0 |            5 |  0 |      0 |  1 |  0 |   1 |
|      0 |    0 |    0 |            6 |  0 |      0 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
+--------+------+------+--------------+----+--------+----+----+-----+
```

**Actual Result:**

```
+--------+------+------+--------------+----+-------+----+----+-----+
| RESALE | COST | Adj. | Quote_Rev_id | PM |  NM   | PR | PQ | PNQ |
+--------+------+------+--------------+----+-------+----+----+-----+
|   1000 | 1000 |   12 |            1 |  0 |  -0.8 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|   2200 | 2200 |   22 |            2 |  0 | -0.82 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|   1200 | 1200 |   12 |            3 |  0 | -0.66 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
|   3900 | 3900 |    2 |            4 |  0 |  0.05 |  1 |  1 |   0 |
+--------+------+------+--------------+----+-------+----+----+-----+
```

Please suggest how to achieve expected result from the given query.

Thanks

Comment: the requirement is little weird.

Comment: Could you please post  formatted data rows for Expected and Actual result?

Comment: Could you describe the business rules used to calculate these values? It is very difficult to guess, looking at this giant query, what is going on and what exactly is to be calculated.